# Modal launched from Bubble

Tags: bubble.io

I'm building an app on Bubble. The app allows the user to create a notification in Bubble that will appear in a modal on their web app or website.

Does anyone have ideas on where to get started with building this? I'm imagining a solution similar to intercom's:
https://developers.intercom.com/installing-intercom/web/installation/